# How to change the page no. of a page's search result for Web Scraping using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping data from a webpage which contains search results using Python.
I am able to scrape data from the 1st search result page.

I want to loop using the same code, changing the search result page with each loop cycle.

Is there any way to do it? Is there a way to click 'Next' button without actually opening the page in a browser?

Comment: Can you post your current script?

Answer (score 0):

At a high level this is possible, you will need to use requests or selenium in addition to beautifulsoup.

Here is an example of defining a element and clicking the button by xpath:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
sleep(1) # Time in seconds.
ele =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tfoot/tr/td/div//button[contains(text(),'Next')]")
ele.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do what you described.  Although you didn't post an actual couple solutions to help you get started.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.bolsamadrid.es/ing/aspx/Empresas/Empresas.aspx"

res = requests.get(url,headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

for page in range(7):
    formdata = {}
    for item in soup.select("#aspnetForm input"):
        if "ctl00$Contenido$GoPag" in item.get("name"):
            formdata[item.get("name")] = page
        else:
            formdata[item.get("name")] = item.get("value")

    req = requests.post(url,data=formdata)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#ctl00_Contenido_tblEmisoras tr")[1:]:
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]
        print(data)
```